# How to unpack a list into variables in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

In Python I can write something like:

```
my_list = [4, 7, "test"]
a, b, c = my_list
```

After that `a` is `4`, `b` is `7` and `c` is `"test"` because of the unpack operation in the last line. Can I do something like the last line in Tcl? To make it more clear, I want something like that:

```
set my_list {4 7 test}
setfromlist $mylist a b c
```

(I.e. `setfromlist` would be the command I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want lassign:

```
% lassign
wrong # args: should be "lassign list ?varName ...?"
% lassign {1 2 3} a b c
% set a
1
% set b
2
% set c
3
```

If you're using an older version of Tcl (that doesn't have lassign), you can use foreach to achieve the same result

```
foreach {a b c} {1 2 3} {break}
```

Comment: lassign comes standard on Tcl 8.5. If you are using Tcl 8.4:

    package require Tclx

Comment: Or, if you don't want all of Tclx, you can just write a version of lassign that uses foreach to achieve the same functionality (foreach was commonly used for this purpose prior to the addition of lassign)